# How can I recursively update an array with a spit and splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, replace

I would really appreciate some help on this - thank you in advance!

The code needs to do the following:

It needs to loop through a `[text]` array. Wherever it finds `%${extLinks[i].subject}%` is should replace that piece of text with an object `{subject: extLinks[i].subject, target: extLinks[i].target}` and add it to the array.

EDIT: 
---Also, only the FIRST instance of the `subject+target` should be replaced and the other instances, ignored.

It has to be reusable too - with different combinations of `subject+target` throughout the whole database (of like, about 700 linked subjects!)---

Here is where I'm at with it:

```
addLinks(synopsis, extLinks = []) {
    let text = synopsis
    for (let i = 0; i < extLinks.length; i++) {
      text = text.replace(extLinks[i].subject, `%${extLinks[i].subject}%`)
    }
    let items = [text]

    extLinks.map(link => {
      let arr = []
      for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        console.log(items)
        arr = items[j].split(`%${link.subject}%`)
        arr.splice(1, 0, {
          subject: extLinks[j].subject,
          target: extLinks[j].target,
        })
        items = arr.splice(0)
      }
    })

    console.log({ items })

    return [synopsis]
  }
```

The expected return is this:

```
["Striking from a fortress hidden among the billion stars of the ", {"subject": "GALAXY", "target": "https://teara.govt.nz/mi/te-mana-o-te-wahine/page-1"}, ", rebel spaceships have won their first victory in a battle with the powerful Imperial Starfleet.  The ", { "subject": "EMPIRE", "target": "https://teara.govt.nz/mi/te-mana-o-te-wahine"  }, "  fears that another defeat could bring a thousand more solar systems into the rebellion, and Imperial control over the GALAXY would be lost forever. Here's another sentence with EMPIRE in it."]
```

But the current code it is returning this:

```
["Striking from a fortress hidden among the billion stars of the %GALAXY%, rebel spaceships have won their first victory in a battle with the powerful Imperial Starfleet.  The %EMPIRE% fears that another defeat could bring a thousand more solar systems into the rebellion, and Imperial control over the GALAXY would be lost forever. Here's another sentence with EMPIRE in it."]
```

so - it’s not creating the final array correctly and it has something to do with the way I need to update the array recursively.

fyi The database object I'm working with looks like this:

`"content": {
       ...
        "synopsis": {
          ...
          "long":
            "Striking from a fortress hidden among the billion stars of the GALAXY, rebel spaceships have won their first victory in a battle with the powerful Imperial Starfleet.  The EMPIRE fears that another defeat could bring a thousand more solar systems into the rebellion, and Imperial control over the GALAXY would be lost forever. Here's another sentence with EMPIRE in it.",
         ...
          ]
        },
          "external links": [
          {
            "subject": "EMPIRE",
            "target": "https://teara.govt.nz/mi/te-mana-o-te-wahine"
          },
          {
            "subject": "GALAXY",
            "target": "https://teara.govt.nz/mi/te-mana-o-te-wahine/page-1"
          }
          ],`

Comment: Based on your `It should return this`, it looks as if each word is only replaced *once*? That is, there's only one resulting `GALAXY` object, while `'GALAXY'` the substring continues to appear later in the string, which hasn't been replaced?

Comment: What about **sprintf**?

Comment: Yes - correct I should add that into the description. Thanks for picking up on it

Comment: Please re-read your question and edit it properly as it is not making proper sense and is a lot confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
function injectLinksIntoSynopsis (synopsis = '', links = []) {
  const linkDictionary = links.reduce((obj, link) => {
    obj[link.subject] = link
    return obj
  }, {})
  const linkMatch = new RegExp(`(${links.map(link => link.subject).join('|')})`, 'g')
  return synopsis
    .split(linkMatch)
    .map(val => {
      return linkDictionary[val] || val
    })
}
```

Basically

1. Turn all your link subjects into an inclusive Regex `/(GALAXY|EMPIRE)/g`. This means when you split your string you will get the values matched in the Regex as well.
2. Split your `synopsis` into an array of link and non-link values
3. Create a dictionary of links your links for lookup (cleaner and easier to read than using index). `{GALAXY: {subject: 'GALAXY', target: 'https://teara.govt.nz/mi/te-mana-o-te-wahine/page-1'}}`
4. Then map over each value and return it or it's mapped value in the dictionary.

Working example here https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/9342nzj5/52/

---

If you want to just replace the first instance of the matched item how about something jazzy like this,

```
function injectFirstLinkIntoSynopsis (synopsis = '', links = []) {
  let stringifiedArray = links.reduce((newSynopsis, link) => {
    return newSynopsis.replace(link.subject, `", ${JSON.stringify(link)}, "`)
  }, `["${synopsis}"]`)
  return JSON.parse(stringifiedArray)
}
```

We iterate over your links and replace the first instance of their subject with a `stringified` Object. We then just `JSON.parse()` it back into an Array once we are done.

I'm personally a big fan of this solution because of my abuse of the `JSON` API's :)

New working example here https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/9342nzj5/76/

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your suggestion. I have updated my question with a couple of details I should have included. Do you think I could adapt your answer to meet these news rules?

Comment: Hey thanks so much - this totally works exactly how we need it to!! Awesome stuff - thank you!